# make loop run endlesly starting from 1 when it reaches max

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this loop which runs like I want it every 5 seconds updating, but I want it to start from beginning when it reaches 20
I tried if [image]statement, but I guess I do something wrong,

I want I to be 1 when it is 20 without breaking the loop
I tried

[image]thank you

Comment: could you please elaborate more regarding your problem. Since it is not clear what are your requirement and issue.

Comment: yea, thx, basically i have this loop running which updates picture on screen from array every couple seconds, and what i want is for it to run endlessly, when it reaches 20th picture it should go back to 1st one endlessly without breaking the loop and timing

Answer (score 0):

As per the description and comments, the requirement is the loop should execute infinitely without breaking and should count from 1 -> 20 -> 1.

For this, following code can be used:

```js
function task(profileIndex) {
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            currentPage = profileIndex + 1; // For 0 it would be 1, for 19 it would be 20
            // Following line would take care of infinite loop
            task((profileIndex + 1) % 20); // % 20 will take care of resetting it to 0 when (profileIndex + 1) is 20. Otherwise, it won't do any manipulation.
        },
        500 // After every 500ms, the page would be updated.
    )
}

task(0)
```